# Sliding Tabs With RecyclerView Showing Blank

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am using Sliding tabs with RecyclerView to show text and images and I think I have it setup correctly but for some reason it is just showing blank in each tab can someone please tell me what is wrong?

This is how it should look

[image]

But it's just showing nothing/blank

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    tabs.setDividerColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    tabs.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTest));
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] adapter_one_tabs;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        adapter_one_tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adapter_one_tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return MyFragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return adapter_one_tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}


public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAB_POSITION_KEY = "TAB_POSITION_KEY";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY, position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_fragment, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        int position = bundle.getInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                break;

            case 1:

                mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                break;

            case 2:

                mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                break;

            case 3:

                mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                break;

        }

        return layout;
    }

}

}
```

AdapterOne

```
public class AdapterOne extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOne.ViewHolder> {

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public AdapterOne() {
super();
mItems = new ArrayList<AdapterData>();
AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.afghanistan);
data.setName("Afghanistan");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.albania);
data.setName("Albania");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.algeria);
data.setName("Algeria");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.american_samoa);
data.setName("American Samoa");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.andorra);
data.setName("Andorra");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.angola);
data.setName("Angola");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.anguilla);
data.setName("Anguilla");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.antigua_and_barbuda);
data.setName("Antigua and Barbuda");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.argentina);
data.setName("Argentina");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.armenia);
data.setName("Armenia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.aruba);
data.setName("Aruba");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.australia);
data.setName("Australia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.austria);
data.setName("Austria");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.azerbaijan);
data.setName("Azerbaijan");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bahamas);
data.setName("Bahamas");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bahrain);
data.setName("Bahrain");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bangladesh);
data.setName("Bangladesh");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.barbados);
data.setName("Barbados");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.belarus);
data.setName("Belarus");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.belgium);
data.setName("Belgium");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.belize);
data.setName("Belize");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.benin);
data.setName("Benin");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bermuda);
data.setName("Bermuda");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bhutan);
data.setName("Bhutan");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bolivia);
data.setName("Bolivia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bosnia_and_herzegovina);
data.setName("Bosnia and Herzegovina");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.botswana);
data.setName("Botswana");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.brazil);
data.setName("Brazil");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.british_virgin_islands);
data.setName("British Virgin Islands");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.brunei);
data.setName("Brunei");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bulgaria);
data.setName("Bulgaria");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.burkina_faso);
data.setName("Burkina Faso");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.burundi);
data.setName("Burundi");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cambodia);
data.setName("Cambodia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cameroon);
data.setName("Cameroon");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.canada);
data.setName("Canada");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cape_verde);
data.setName("Cape Verde");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cayman_islands);
data.setName("Cayman Islands");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.central_african_republic);
data.setName("Central African Republic");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.chad);
data.setName("Chad");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.chile);
data.setName("Chile");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.china);
data.setName("China");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.colombia);
data.setName("Colombia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.comoros);
data.setName("Comoros");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cook_islands);
data.setName("Cook Islands");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.costa_rica);
data.setName("Costa Rica");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cote_divoire);
data.setName("Cote d'Ivoire");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.croatia);
data.setName("Croatia");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cuba);
data.setName("Cuba");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cayman_islands);
data.setName("Cayman Island");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.curacao);
data.setName("Curacao");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cyprus);
data.setName("Cyprus");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.czech_republic);
data.setName("Czech Republic");
mItems.add(data);

data = new AdapterData();
data.setThumbnail(R.drawable.democratic_republic_of_the_congo);
data.setName("Democratic Republic of the Congo");
mItems.add(data);


}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
AdapterData movie = mItems.get(i);
viewHolder.natThumbnail.setImageResource(movie.getThumbnail());
viewHolder.natName.setText(movie.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public ImageView natThumbnail;
public TextView natName;


public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    natThumbnail =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutThumbnail);
    natName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutName);
}
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

recyclerview_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

recycler_view_card_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DDD">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/layoutThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/afghanistan"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/layoutName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country Name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutThumbnail"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

your view pager height is `0dp`. That's the error. Make it `match_parent` or something.